# Get data from relational tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following tables in my db.

Calls:

```
ID  Name
1   Call1
2   Call2
3   Call3
```

Notes:

```
ID  Name
1   Note 1
2   Note 2
```

Person:

```
ID  Name
1   Andrew
```

PersonCalls:

```
ID  CallID  PersonID
1   1       1
2   2       1
```

PersonNotes:

```
ID   NoteID  PersonID
1    1       1
1    2       1
```

Now I need to get data from these tables according to person id. I am able to get data from 2 tables, for example Notes and PersonNotes, but I am not able to get combined data from these tables. This should be the result.

Result:

```
PersonID    Note    Call
1           Note1   Call1
1           Note2   Call2
```

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: What are your requirements for the result?  What is the logic? What should it look like?

Comment: My requirement is to get result like this

personID  Note  Call
1         Note1 Call1
1         Note2 Call2
1         ----- Call3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use Join** (**ie:** Inner Join):

```
select distinct p.ID as PersonID, n.Name as Note, c.Name as Call from Person p
inner join PersonCalls pc on p.ID = pc.PersonID
inner join PersonNotes pn on p.ID = pn.PersonID
inner join Calls c on pc.CallID = c.ID
inner join Notes n on pn.NoteID = n.ID
```

Comment: What made you think so?  For example, it seems that in `PersonNotes` and `PersonCalls` the **foreign** key is `PersonID'.

Comment: There you go. Because the table was messy before, I couldn't figure out what was what.

Comment: It's also possible that based on actual OP's requirements some or all of `JOIN`s would need to be `OUTER`.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, your query returns data but there are a lot of duplicate records.

Comment: Ravi, I have updated my question and added expected result, please check and let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too detailed you can use a left join on dbo.calls.ID, dbo.notes.id, dbo.person.id, etc if you are using MS SQL server. Otherwise are you sure you can't just write a report?